# Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted

Tags: swift, realm

I'm very new to programming.
I am trying to update an object in my Realm database but I get always an error.
I have tried to find the issue but I can't find anyone with a similar issue.

What I'm trying to do is:
I have a Game-Score-App.
It should display the names on Tab1 and on the Tab2 I want to give the user the ability, to change the names of the players. As soon as the ViewDidDisappear I want to write the changes to Realm.

I already figured out how to update the names in the database. And it works properly the first time.
But as soon as I go a second time on the Tab2 and go back to Tab1 again, I get the message "Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted."

Any Ideas?

```
class Games: Object {
@objc dynamic var game_id = UUID().uuidString
@objc dynamic var gameName: String = ""
var playerNames = List<String>()

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "game_id"
}
```

}

```
class FirstPageVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var playerNameLabels: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet weak var gameNameLabel: UILabel!

let realm = try! Realm()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    let games = realm.objects(Games.self)
    gameNameLabel.text = games[0].gameName
    for i in 0...playerNameLabels.count - 1 {
        playerNameLabels[i].text = games[0].playerNames[i]
    }
}
```

}

```
class SecondPageVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var playerNameTextbox: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet weak var gameNameTextbox: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfIndex: UITextField!

let realm = try! Realm()
var playerNames: [String] = []
var gameName: String = ""
var game = Games()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if realm.objects(Games.self).count != 0 {
        let games = realm.objects(Games.self)
        gameNameTextbox.text = games[0].gameName
        for i in 0...playerNameTextbox.count - 1 {
            playerNameTextbox[i].text = games[0].playerNames[i]
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    gameName = gameNameTextbox.text!
    for i in 0...playerNameTextbox.count - 1 {
        playerNames.append(playerNameTextbox[i].text!)
    }

    let items = realm.objects(Games.self)
    let number = Int(numberOfIndex.text!)
    
    game.game_id = items[number!].game_id
    game.gameName = gameName
    game.playerNames.append(objectsIn: playerNames)

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(game, update: .modified)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A primary key is what uniquely identifies an object in the database so if you would change that for an object then it can not be correctly identified any more and this is what the error tells you. The best solution for you is to add another property perhaps of type Int or UUID and let that property be the primary key so that you can modify the name. I can't help you with an exact way to do it since I don't know Realm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your Realm object structure. Anything that could possibly *ever* be changed should not be used as a primary key.

Also note from the [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys)

> Once an object with a primary key is added to a Realm, the primary key
> cannot be changed.

To expand on that, it's often best practice to disassociate an objects key (e.g. primary key) from the rest of the properties of an object.

Here's how to do that

```
class Games: Object{
   @objc dynamic var game_id = UUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var gameName: String = ""
   var playerNames = List<String>()

   override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "game_id"
   }
}
```

UUID().uuidString will generate a unique string for every object that's created and will look something like this string

```
CDEA69EA-AC84-4465-ABE3-DDA29D31B925
```

Once the object is created, you can use it to load that specific object or update it's properties.

See [Objects with Primary Keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys)

Here's how to change the game name

```
let item = realm.object(ofType: Game.self, forPrimaryKey: "CDEA69EA-AC84-4465-ABE3-DDA29D31B925")!

try! realm.write {
    game.gameName = "Pwn You!"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jay for your suggestion. I have changed now my code based on your improvements but I still get the same issue, as soon as I want to update the new values. Here is my Code:
        game.game_id = "CDEA69EA-AC84-4465-ABE3-DDA29D31B925"
        game.gameName = gameName
        game.playerNames.append(objectsIn: playerNames)
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(game, update: .modified)
        }

Comment: @Flo If you're getting the same message "Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted" then you're still trying to change that and it cannot be changed. Ensure you've updated your object to have a different primary key property and also ensure you've updated the `override class func primaryKey()` function to point to that new property, not the gameName property.

Comment: I am sorry I may be too stupid I don't get my fault. I have edited my original question with the new code I wrote. I have added a button on my VC and a textbox to add and change my inputs, but still, the first time I change my data in the database everything works and it updates with the new values, the second time it crashes with the error message.

Comment: @Flo What's happening is the first time you go to the view controller a new Games object is created `var game = Games()`. Then it's populated and *written to realm*. At that point the game object is now managed. The next time you go to that viewController, the game object is still in scope so a new one is not created. Therefore when you try to modify it outside a write, it crashes. There doesn't appear to be a reason that `game` is a class var as it looks like the intention is to create a new Game inside the add function. If so, create the var inside the addButton function

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

**Replace** the code in **viewDidDisappear** after the end of for loop with the following code:

```
if let gameInRealm = realm.objects(Game.self).first{
    try! realm.write {
        gameInRealm.gameName = gameName
        gameInRealm.playerNames = playerNames
    }
}else{
    game.gameName = gameName
    game.playerNames.append(objectsIn: playerNames)
    realm.add(game)
}
```

**Explanation** (if needed):

The code changes the existing Game properties in case a Game object exists. Otherwise, it creates a new one with the new properties.

Therefore, the else statement should get executed the first time you leave SecondPageVC, and then the if statement will get triggered every other time you leave SecondPageVC.